# xml to meaningful conversation in excel format

Tags: xml, excel, selenium, xml-parsing, export-to-excel

I have automated a web page using selenium web driver and output the test results in an xml file. Here's the file :

```
<Log>
  <Tests>
    <ModuleName>Login</ModuleName>
    <TestName>Welcome Label</TestName>
    <DateAndTime>2014-59-02 03:59:31</DateAndTime>
    <Result>Passed</Result>
  </Tests>
  <Tests>
    <ModuleName>Login</ModuleName>
    <TestName>Username Label</TestName>
    <DateAndTime>2014-59-02 03:59:32</DateAndTime>
    <Result>Failed</Result>
  </Tests>
  <Tests>
    <ModuleName>Login</ModuleName>
    <TestName>Password Label</TestName>
    <DateAndTime>2014-59-02 03:59:32</DateAndTime>
    <Result>Passed</Result>
  </Tests>
  <Tests>
    <ModuleName>Login</ModuleName>
    <TestName>Login Button Label</TestName>
    <DateAndTime>2014-59-02 03:59:32</DateAndTime>
    <Result>Failed</Result>
  </Tests>
</Log>
```

Now here, the Result Tag shows whether the test has "Passed" or "Failed". I would like to read this xml file and output into excel file which will color Green for the "Passed" Test cases and "Red" for the "Failed" Test cases. Obviously the column names will be according to the tag specified (here it will be Module Name, Test Name, Date and Time, Result sequentially). How to can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your xml to excel using POI APi in java..

For reference click bellow link

[xml to excel by java](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076189/enterprise-java/book-excerpt--converting-xml-to-spreadsheet--and-vice-versa.html?page=2)

you have to use this code snippet ...for  **Result** column in excel

```
 HSSFCellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
    style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIME.index);
    style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

    HSSFFont font = wb.createFont();
    String result=((Element) (nodeList.item(0))) //getting result tag value from xml
                   .getElementsByTagName("generaladmin").item(0)
                   .getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

    if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("Passed"))//set the color to cell based on result string value
       font.setColor(HSSFColor.GREEN.index);
    else if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("Red"))
       font.setColor(HSSFColor.RED.index);
    style.setFont(font);

    cell.setCellStyle(style);
    cell.setCellValue(result);
```